# Authentication gem to use for Neo4j and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, neo4j

Any suggestions regarding implementation of authentication mechanism in a project using Rails 4 and Neo4j?

`gem devise-neo4j` https://github.com/benjackson/devise-neo4j/ is no longer mantained

Unable to find any good resource describing the implementation of authentication mechanism in Rails 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gemfile, use `gem 'devise-neo4j', "~> 2.0.0.alpha.1"`. It was updated earlier this year to support Neo4jrb v3.

Comment: Thanks @subvertailchris for the information. Wasn't able to find any resource pointing to the integration of Devise, Rails 4 and Neo4j. Will surely contribute to a blog post describing this integration in detail by myself.

Comment: @Cody I'm going to start working on more extensive docs for the gem and related projects soon. In the meantime, all you need to do to get it working is add the properties and indexes required by Devise to your model. The devise-neo4j's GH page says there's a generator but I haven't used it, it's easy enough to get started. You can shoot me an email if you have any trouble, it's in my profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot @subvertailchris, will surely contact if require any help.